# error while including boost libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

So this is the first time i've done any multi-threading in C++.  Right now my code is throwing some kind of error i can't identify but it seems to indicate that it occurs when i include boost/thread.hpp.

The error look something like this.

```
  In file included 

             from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
             from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
             from processes/Video_process.h:8,
             from processes/Video_process.cpp:7:

             /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp: In member function ‘R& boost::_mfi::dm<R, T>::operator()(T*) const [with R = void*(void*), T = Video_process]’:
             /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:243:60:   instantiated from ‘R boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<R>, F&, A&, long int) [with R = void* (&)(void*), F = boost::_mfi::dm<void*(void*), Video_process>, A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::_bi::value<Video_process*>]’

             /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:   instantiated from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void* (&)(void*), F = boost::_mfi::dm<void*(void*), Video_process>, L = boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<Video_process*> >, boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void* (&)(void*)]’
             /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:61:17:   instantiated from ‘void boost::detail::thread_data<F>::run() [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void* (&)(void*), boost::_mfi::dm<void*(void*), Video_process>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<Video_process*> > >]’
             processes/Video_process.cpp:240:1:   instantiated from here
             /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:342:23: error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

my codes a bit long so i dont know which bits if any would be useful but here are some anyways...

1.

```
  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mx); 
  lock.lock();
    (...) //stuff
  is_data_ready = 1;
  lock.unlock();
```

2.

```
stserver = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>
 (new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Video_process::streamServer, this)));
```

Here is how streamServer is declared in the header

```
void* streamServer(void* arg);
```

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `Video_process::streamServer` please?

Comment: kk got it here is the line from the header file or did u mean the function's code???

Comment: A declaration is the function prototype with no definition (function body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that shows in `boost::bind` basically says that your member function `void* Video_process::streamServer(void* arg)` expects two arguments `this` and `void*`. Your code only binds the first argument.

If you'd like to use it with `boost::thread` it shouldn't require the second `void*` argument or have it bound to a constant. Also, `boost::thread` discards the return value of the functor, so you may like to use `void`, i.e.:

```
struct Video_process {
    void streamServer();
};

boost::thread(boost::bind(&Video_process::streamServer, this));
// or simply
boost::thread(&Video_process::streamServer, this);
```

With regards to:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mx); 
lock.lock();
```

The first line locks the mutex in the constructor, so the second line with explicit lock is unnecessary.